# Is it possible statically linking Apache 2.0, BSD-2, or MIT libraries to AGPL v3.0 binaries?

Tags: license-compatibility, apache-2.0, lgpl, agpl-3.0, android

## TL; DR

We are considering creating a series of dependency modules (UI, repository patterns, etc) as separated Android libraries.

Could we use a permissive license (Apache 2.0, BSD-2 or MIT) despite statically linking them into another AGPL v3.0 *app* project?

## Details

### Android Clean Architecture

One of the many reasons for adopting architecture on [Android apps](https://fivenyc.medium.com/android-architecture-part-1-every-new-beginning-is-hard-132a65507f48) is simplify testability isolating the business cases code from modules that require Android dependencies.

[image: Android Clean Architecture, by Five Agency]

Business cases (or interactors) are implemented like [command pattern](https://youtu.be/Nsjsiz2A9mg?t=900) instances.

With no Android framework dependencies at the `domain` module, the network/cache and sensors boilerplate moved into `data` and `device` modules respectively.

In the current model:

- All modules depended on `domain` because `app`, `data` and `device` implement interfaces defined by `domain`
- `data` depends on `domain` interfaces only
- `device` depends on `domain` interfaces only
- `app` depends on `domain` module
- `data` and `device` are injected into `app`

### Permissive vs Strongly Protected Licenses

Unlike `*.deb` or `*.rpm` packages in a common Linux distribution, Android apps required static linking to its dependencies. Unless you are using a permissive dependency, the viral nature of (L)GPL forces the developer publish the whole app content, i.e. *"thou shalt not use AGPL, GPL or LGPL dependencies."*

[image: opensource-flow-img]

### The Mexican standoff

Given **only `data` uses a AGPLv3.0 library**, could we:

1. **Release `device` and `domain` as a Apache 2.0? project**  (My guts say *yes*)
2. **Release `app` as another Apache 2.0? project** (My guts say *no*)

The intention is allow other developers use our code (like Airbnb [Epoxy](https://github.com/airbnb/epoxy) and [MvRx](https://github.com/airbnb/MvRx)) at their projects, but keep **only** the core technology under **AGPL v3.0**.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From what you've written, I'm not entirely clear about the problem.  I'm going to assume that you're the sole rightsholder in `{data,domain,app,device}.gradle` (forgive the regexp) and that `data.gradle`, though written entirely by you, is linked to a third-party AGPLv3 library.  Thus `{domain,app,device}.gradle` are unconstrained with respect to licence, but `data.gradle` must be distributed under AGPLv3.  Given that the intent is for all four of your modules to be compiled into a single binary, you want to know what your options are.

The first important point is that **licences do not inhere in code, they attach to recipients through the act of conveyance**.  The second important point is that the FSF has [something to say](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#GPLModuleLicense) about this issue:

> The GPL says that the whole combined program has to be released under the GPL. So your module has to be available for use under the GPL.
>
> But you can give additional permission for the use of your code. You can, if you wish, release your module under a license which is more lax than the GPL but compatible with the GPL.

So when you release the combined binary, and complete corresponding source, this must indeed be under AGPLv3 (*per* ss 4-6), but that does not prevent you from also releasing `{domain,app,device}.gradle` **separately** under more-permissive but compatible licences (which would include Apache2).

Have I understood the question correctly, and does this answer it?

Comment: Likely, it would also be allowed to license the *source code* of `data.gradle` under a permissive license: it is only the *binaries* that contain an AGPL component.

Comment: @amon I think you are likely right, but since I'm not yet sure that I understood the question, I thought I'd keep it brief until clarification followed.

Comment: Great @MadHatter!! You have understood perfectly!!! The Android app already is published as GPL v3.0 and the server AGPL v3.0.

Comment: @JPVentura oh good!  Does it answer your question?

Comment: @amon Apache v2.0 and MIT dominate mobile apps ecosystem due the viral nature of (L)GPL v3.0 regarding static linking. I am trying to figure out if a modular app would allow to circumvent this limitation, publishing most of the code as Apache 2.0.

Comment: @MadHatter you did in fact. Releasing the application at Google Play under GPL v.3.0 is perfect, I am just wondering how much of the final project would have to be under the same license. Seems like only the "builder" module, right?

Comment: @JPVentura then feel free to accept the answer <grin>.  "*I am just wondering how much of the final project would have to be under the same license"* it depends how you're distributing it.  When it's conveyed compiled into an application, or in the complete corresponding source of that application, **all** of it must be conveyed under AGPLv3.  When your work is conveyed as standalone pieces of code, any AGPLv3-compatible licence will do.